# .toggle() infinite and unsure toggling of class names

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't understand why there's having a problem with `.toggle()` when toggling class names with animations. Consider this experiment I made:

```js
var query = document.querySelector.bind(document);

query('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  [].forEach.call(query('.container').children, function(box, i) {
    setInterval(function() {
      box.classList.toggle('popIn');
    }, 300 * i);
  })
})
```

```css
.container > .box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: cyan;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.container > .box.popIn {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

When I click the button, it toggles the class names of boxes indefinitely as if it's not sure if it adds or removes them. Is it because the `.toggle()` method is inside a `forEach` loop?

Comment: Its because of the `setInterval()`

Comment: Use `setTimeout`, not `setInterval`

Answer (score 0):

You're issue is in the setInterval function.  You are saying, perform this event every 300ms.  What you want is setTimeout, which is telling the event to stop after 300ms.  See the below snippet where I have made the change.

See more information on [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)
See more information on [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

```js
var query = document.querySelector.bind(document);

query('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  [].forEach.call(query('.container').children, function(box, i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      box.classList.toggle('popIn');
    }, 300 * i);
  })
})
```

```css
.container > .box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: cyan;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.container > .box.popIn {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot :)